# How to apply Jensen's inequality to expected error term of an ensemble model

Tags: expected-value, jensen-inequality, mean-square-error

Consider a convex function $f(x) = x^2$

Let $E_{AV} = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^{M} \mathbb{E}_x [(y_m(x) - f(x))^2]$ be average expected sum-of-squares error of the members of an ensemble model

Let $E_{ENS} = \mathbb{E}_x [(\frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^{M} y_m(x) - f(x))^2]$ be the expected error of an ensemble model.

How can we show that
$\mathbb{E}_{ENS} \le \mathbb{E}_{AV}$
by applying Jensen Inequality?

Comment: You have typed the same thing for $E_{AV}$ and $E_{ENS}$

Comment: Now, corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(\frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^{M} (y_m(x) - f(x)))^2 \leq \frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^{M} (y_m(x) - f(x))^2$ by Jensen's Inequality applied to the uniform measure on $\{1,2,...,M\}$. Now just take expectation on both sides.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is the above result holds for any error function, not just sum-of-squares, as long as it is convex?

Comment: Yes, the only ingredient of my proof is convexity of $x \to x^{2}$. @TuhinDutta